# Помогите задать Background через attr() если это возможно

Tags: html, css

Допустим мне надо задать `background` через `attr()` подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.
Я сделал такой код, но он не работает :

```css
.cart {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  background: attr(data-url-bg);
}

.cart2 {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  background: url(attr(data-url-bg));
}

img {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  background: url("https://i.artfile.ru/2560x1706_1283206_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg");
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart" data-url-bg="url('https://i.artfile.ru/2560x1706_1283206_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg')">
</div>
<div class="cart2" data-url-bg="https://i.artfile.ru/2560x1706_1283206_[www.ArtFile.ru].jpg">
</div>
<img>
```

Вот представлены 2 моих попытки и доказательство что ссылка не битая в виде `<img>`

Comment: `<div style="background-image:url(img-url.png)"></div>`

Comment: мне надо через использование attr! потому что дам будет вариативность

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, attr нормально не поддерживается ни одним браузером

Comment: понял спасибо, но работает например такое: `<div data-bef="before" class="exm"></div>` [[style  .exm:before {"content: attr(data-bef)"}]]

Comment: Вот только такое и работает, а больше ничего связанное с attr толком не работает

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#url - ваша конструкция работать не будет, так как url принимает только строку, кроме того решение со стилями ничем не ограничивается

Comment: @andreymal, скорее `attr` не для `content` не поддерживается.

Comment: @andreymal разве в конечном итоге attr не выдает строку-значение атрибута?